# Delete oldest versions of a directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of directories which are formatted like version numbers and would like to find the N oldest directories and delete them. For example:

```
/1.2.3.4
/1.2.3.5
/1.2.3.6
```

I've tried a few things, but I can't quite seem to get where I need to go.

My first try was this:

```
ls directory | sort Name | select -first 5 | rm -r
```

However I'm not sure this is going to work in all circumstances, because this will (I presume) do a natural sort. Is that always going to return the correct results?

My next thought was that I could use `System.Version` to do my sorting. So I ended up with this:

```
ls directory | %{[System.Version]$_.Name } | sort | select -first 5 | ???
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to tie the directory result to the sorting... What's the best way to do this?

`gci \\directory` produces

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        12/19/2011   5:19 PM            1.0.1052.54849
d----        12/19/2011   5:29 PM            1.0.1053.54850
d----        12/19/2011   5:36 PM            1.0.1054.54851
d----        12/20/2011   2:11 PM            1.0.1056.54875
d----        12/12/2011  10:39 AM            1.0.991.54625
d----        12/12/2011  12:08 PM            1.0.992.54627
d----        12/12/2011  12:22 PM            1.0.993.54628
d----        12/12/2011   1:15 PM            1.0.994.54630
d----        12/12/2011   2:45 PM            1.0.996.54636
d----        12/12/2011   3:34 PM            1.0.997.54640
d----        12/12/2011   3:48 PM            1.0.998.54641
```

`gci \\directory | Sort-Object { $_Name -as [Version] }` produces

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        12/12/2011   1:15 PM            1.0.994.54630
d----        12/12/2011  12:22 PM            1.0.993.54628
d----        12/12/2011   2:45 PM            1.0.996.54636
d----        12/12/2011   3:48 PM            1.0.998.54641
d----        12/12/2011   3:34 PM            1.0.997.54640
d----        12/12/2011  12:08 PM            1.0.992.54627
d----        12/19/2011   5:29 PM            1.0.1053.54850
d----        12/19/2011   5:19 PM            1.0.1052.54849
d----        12/19/2011   5:36 PM            1.0.1054.54851
d----        12/12/2011  10:39 AM            1.0.991.54625
d----        12/20/2011   2:11 PM            1.0.1056.54875
```

Does it matter that this is a network share? I'm confused as to why this isn't working... I did a quick sanity check and doing `Array.Sort` on versions I've created in a unit test are sorted correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a . :  Sort-Object {$_.Name -as [version] }, not Sort-OBject { $_Name -as [Version] }

Comment: I noticed that just after posting this, excuse my fat fingers. Out of interest, why didn't that throw an error? Is it just trying to find a variable $_Name and not finding it and trying to pass null to the constructor?

Comment: Property accesses in PowerShell never throw errors (they do write to $error), but instead just return nulls.  This is so that when you show an object where some properties don't work, you don't interleave error and output.  You can switch how PowerShell treats this by turning on Strict mode:  Set-StrictMode -Version Latest.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually sort on an expression, which will keep your original objects.

```
Get-ChildItem $path  |
    Sort-Object { $_.Name -as [Version] } |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Remove-Item
```

Will do the trick.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This is elegant, not for the `-as` operator, but the expression. didn't realize you can do that.

Comment: The same holds true for Select-Object & Group-Object.  You learn a thing or a thousand when you work on the product team for a whole ship cycle and then found a company that specializes in the language :-)  This is definately one of my favorite nooks and crannies of the core PowerShell cmdlets.

This old video covers some of my favorites of the -Object set:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/philpenn/PowerShell--Object-Family-of-CmdLets-and-the-Object-Pipeline

Comment: Doesn't this require line-continuation characters?

Comment: Nope.  The pipeline character ending the line will make the PowerShell parser expect a next step.  Backticks are ugly, and should be avoided when unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Natural sort is the order that you want. 1,2,3..10,11..instead of 1,10,11,2,3..

```
1..11 | %{$_.tostring()} | sort
```

Gives it in "ASCIIbetical" order, which is not the natural order we expect it to be in.

Based on what you were doing with version, I would say you can do like this, though it might be a bit over board:

```
gci directory | %{new-object psobject -p @{version=[version]($_.name);dir=$_ }} | 
sort version | select -expand dir -first 5 | rm -r -whatif
```

or

```
gci directory | select @{e={[version] $_.name};l="version"}, @{e={$_};l="dir"} |
sort version | select -expand dir -first 5 | rm -r -whatif
```

Comment: I was tempted to try to put the intermediate results into an object, maybe a `Tuple` or dictionary... I'll give this a try and let you know how I get on.